# Error while using template or placement new

Tags: c++

I have written an allocator class but it would not compile

```
template<typename T>
class Alloc_my {
public:
    T* allocate(int n) { return static_cast<T*>(malloc(n * sizeof(T))); }
    void construct(T* p, const T& v) { T* a = new (p) v; }
    void destroy(T* p) { p->~T(); memset(p, 0, sizeof(T)); }
    void deallocate(T* p) { free(p); }
};
```

Here is an error message:

```
error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token 'identifier', expected 'type specifier'
message : see reference to class template instantiation 'Alloc_my<T>' being compiled
```

Comment: Did you mean `{ T* a = new (p) T(v); }`?

Comment: I did. Is this the syntax?

Comment: @ArtyomGoncharov Yes, you need to say what the type of the new object should be.

Comment: UPD. It's working with ```T(v)```. But why should I use copying constructor while I already signed ```v``` as ```T``` type variable?

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new  If you remove the "placement" part of the declaration, it should still be a valid `new` statement. `T* a = new v;` is invalid, `T* a = new  T(v);` is valid.

Comment: @ArtyomGoncharov Isn't copying the reason for your passing an already-existing object to the function? `new (p) T(arguments)` creates a new `T` instance from the arguments, at the location `p`.

Comment: `T` stands for the type, `v` for its initializer, `p` for the location where it is to be constructed using `v`.

Comment: `new 42;` is invalid syntax, `new int(42);` would be correct.

Comment: Ok, right. I now understand. Thanks everyone